# Add "Please do not use this tag for differential equations" to "functional-equations" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

I would like to add the phrase "Please do not use this tag for differential equations." as first line to the tag [functional-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-equations).

Of course, differential equations ARE functional equations, but this is not the way that I have seen "functional equations" used and it corresponds to the way I want to use the tag (I am interested in answering questions on functional equations different from differential equations) and I cannot imagine someone using "functional-equations" to search for differential equations. It also seems to correspond to the use of other tags.

However, I realize that this is a question where I am not sure what other users think, so I want to give you a chance to weigh in.

---

Examples of questions from last week tagged functional equations:

[Solving the differential equation $f'(x)=af(x+b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623019/solving-the-differential-equation-fx-afxb),

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621696/numerically-solving-delay-differential-equations

[How to solve $(f'(x+1)+f'(x-1))f(x)-(f(x+1)+f(x-1))f'(x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617305/how-to-solve-fx1fx-1fx-fx1fx-1fx-0)

---

Reaction to answers and comments:
You have made me understand why people would reasonably choose these tags. I am not 100% convinced that this is a useful thing, but since the default stance is certainly to let everyone decide on their tags, you have convinced me to do nothing.

Comment: I agree that the tag is inappropriate for differential equations questions. Can you give some examples of the [tag:functional-equations] tag being used for such questions?

Comment: @AlexBecker Phira has edited some examples in.

Comment: Here is a very well known book Introduction to [Functional Differential Equations](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Functional-Differential-Equations-Mathematical/dp/0387940766), which might help to change your mind about this specific question.

Comment: Does http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633385 also belongs to a DDE question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least the questions linked in the OP seem to be about relating values of the function (or its derivatives) at *different* points of the domain in each instance of the equation.

I think this ought to be enough to make the [functional-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-equations) tag apply to the questions, even if the equation *also* involves derivatives. A priori, solving them they might need a combination of tools from both areas.

Comment: In particular, the first two are about [delay differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), which I'm somewhat surprised to see we don't yet have a specific tag for.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I agree, and created [tag:dde].

Comment: @Charles Users are unlikely to know what `dde` means, though. I suggest `delay-differential-eqns` as either a synonym or as the name of the tag.

Answer (score 6):

People should not be searching for/favoriting/subscribing to "functional-equations" to look for Differential Equations. I agree with the Phira's position in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The examples you give (the second excepted) are what I would call functional equations, even if they contain derivatives. Henning Makholm's observation is good: the functional equation contains derivatives, but the relation uses different points in the domain. I have seen problems like those in highschool olympiads, and as a highschool students are concerned, these are not differential equations in the sense university students regard them, but merely functional equations in which derivatives appear.

Examples:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2650932&sid=e11ad1db842ea084166ec64a0ff8d007#p2650932

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=816031&sid=e11ad1db842ea084166ec64a0ff8d007#p816031

In my opinion, these remain functional equations (even if they contain derivatives), and even their solutions might only use tricks or other functional equations techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening links. These are sort of "Putnam functional equations".